# How to tell if mysql stored procedure executed successfully

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that updates two tables and then inserts a row in to a third table. (And to my understanding, rolls back the updates or insert if all three cannot be done) Anyway, whenever I run this procedure, regardless if it ends up successfully running the two updates and insert or not, it will always be "successful" and return false. I need it to return a value (probably true) if it successfully does all two updates and one insert and false if it does not so I can do the correct error checking on the server side.

Here is the procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`db1`@`%` PROCEDURE `completed_procedure`(IN insubmissionid INT)
BEGIN

DECLARE ingregid INT;
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION ROLLBACK;
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLWARNING ROLLBACK;

START TRANSACTION;

SET @ingregid = (SELECT idgreg FROM submission WHERE idsubmission = insubmissionid);

UPDATE submission SET status='a' WHERE idsubmission = insubmissionid;

UPDATE greg SET iscomplete=1 WHERE idgreg = @ingregid;

INSERT INTO completion (idperson, idgreg, datecompleted, idsubmission, mediaid, description,
    privatestatus, contenttype, totalamount)  
SELECT s.idperson, s.idgreg, s.datesubmitted, s.idsubmission,
    COALESCE(s.youtubeid, s.contentid) AS mediaidid, g.description, g.privatestatus,
    g.contenttype, COALESCE(SUM(amount),0) AS totalamount 
FROM submission s 
INNER JOIN greg g on s.idgreg = g.idgreg
INNER JOIN contribution c on s.idgreg = c.idgreg 
WHERE s.idsubmission = insubmissionid AND c.ispaid = 1;

COMMIT;
END
```

What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: You can use `SELECT ROW_COUNT()` after a data modification query to find out if it made any changes.

Comment: @Barmar Could you please show me an example of how this would work to return success = 1 if all updates and insert succeed?

Comment: What do you mean by it returns false? Procedures don't return anything, only functions have a return value.

Comment: What precisely is the success check supposed to check for? If you update a record but it already has the value you assign, it won't be counted in `ROW_COUNT()`, but it's still considered successful. Do you just need to know whether the transaction was committed or had to be rolled back because of an exception?

Comment: Oh yeah, that was my server side function returning false. My mistake. All I want to do is return true to the server if all updates and inserts ran or false if they did not. Is this possible? I thought that was the point of OUT variables? @Barmar

Comment: I want it rolled back if any of the updates or inserts don't actually update or insert something. Anyway I have fixed this problem by using IF and ELSE's. I still don't know how to return to my server if the stored procedure actually succeeded in all 3 updates/insert though.

Comment: See Agu V's answer, it shows how to return a success indication to the caller. Or you could rewrite it as a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could return a value, heres an example.

```
 CREATE DEFINER=`db1`@`%` PROCEDURE `completed_procedure`(IN insubmissionid INT, OUT success INT
BEGIN

IF (   CONDITION  ) THEN
    SET success = 1;
ELSE
    SET success = -1;
END IF;
SELECT success ;

COMMIT;
END
```

Comment: I wasn't sure. Thank you!

Comment: By declaring an OUT variable as a parameter I have to pass in an extra argument for the OUT parameter. Is there a way to just return a variable that I don't have to specify when calling it?

Comment: @Mitchell You don't have to pass the OUT parameter.